# For some reason cannot click a button twice

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

this is my first ever question and would really appreciate you guys' help. I am getting this error everytime I click a button twice. `Uncaught TypeError: (document.getElementById(...).style.display == "block") is not a function`

This is my JS code--

```
document.getElementById("HTML").addEventListener("click", function(){
    
        if (document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display == 'block') 
        (document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display == 'block') 
        (document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display == 'block'); {
            document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display = 'none';
        
        document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
);

document.getElementById("CSS").addEventListener("click", function(){

        if (document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display == 'block') 
        (document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display == 'block') 
        (document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display == 'block'); {
            document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display = 'none';
        
        document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
);

document.getElementById("IMG").addEventListener("click", function(){
    
        if (document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display == 'block') 
        (document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display == 'block') 
        (document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display == 'block'); {
            document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display = 'none';
        
        document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
);

document.getElementById("SVG").addEventListener("click", function(){
    
    if (document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display == 'block') 
    (document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display == 'block') 
    (document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display == 'block'); {
        document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display = 'none';
    
    document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display = 'block';
    }
}
);
```

end everytime I click a button twice it gives me the error. I have tried everything I could to solve this but still no progress.
Thanks!

Comment: Add the HTML. See [mcve].

Comment: For starters you're making a mistake with the syntax of your `if` conditions.  Instead of having `(...)(...)(...)` for each condition you want, you do them in one `(...)` using the proper operator for if you want to say `and` or `or`.  To say `and` you would do `(... && ... && ...)` and to say `or` you would do `(... || ... || ...)`.  You also shouldn't have a `;` after your conditions.  It should be `if(.....) { ..... }` not `if(....); { .... }`.  Try fixing that first and see if you get the results you want :).

Comment: tysm that worked and it no longer shows me the errors. I appreciate you help!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using another parenthesis i.e. `(...)` after the first one for the `if` clause i.e. `if(...)(...)(...)`
Which tries to run the first parenthesis clause `(...)` as a function, which is not a function but a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements)

You should use binary logical operators like [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) between these conditions like `(...) || (...) || (...)`

Also, remove the semi-colon `;` before the first if brace (curly bracket `{...}`)

So, you can try something like

```javascript
// Example code for `HTML` will be the same for all others i.e. CSS, IMG, SVG

document.getElementById("HTML").addEventListener("click", function(){

  if (
    document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display == 'block' ||
    document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display == 'block' ||
    document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display == 'block'
  ) {

      document.getElementById("CSScontent").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("Imgcontent").style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("SVGcontent").style.display = 'none';
        
      document.getElementById("HTMLcontent").style.display = 'block';
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it and it works. (I need to practice my JS) tysm!